# Cannot print a data from SQLServer

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel

I'm creating a proxy with laravel.
Its job is like this:

1. Start and listening on port 8080.
2. When a client sends a request to the proxy, it fetches data from SQLServer according to the request.
3. And then, it sends a response with the fetched data to the client.

My proxy almost works properly. But I got one problem.

My database has a value "0x00000000045F62031".
When the proxy fetched the data from SQLServer, this code

```php
logger($MY_LIST);
```

is not printed in `laravel.log` properly.
It is printed as this.

```
[2020-04-14 15:06:33] local.DEBUG: E? 1
```

It has been garbled and, I could not find the character code with the function `mb_detect_encoding`, it did not print anything.

Other columns in the table was detected as "UTF-8", but only the hexadecimal data was Nothing.

How can I get the hexadecimal data properly?

Comment: You're trying to print the decimal value of the hexadecimal data? You have this function to do that. hexdec("0x00000000045F62031")